# Solving IVP using Laplace Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I would like to solve the IVP

$$y'' + 2y' + 3y = 3t$$

with $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$ using transform methods. Could someone check my work is correct, as my solution differs from that in the text?

***Solution.***

Taking Laplace transforms on both sides,

\begin{align*}
L[y''] + 2L[y'] + 3L[y] &= \frac{1}{s^2} \\
s^2L[y]-sy(0)-y'(0)+2(sL[y]-y(0))+3L[y]&=\frac{1}{s^2}\\
(s^2 + 2s + 3)L[y] + 1 &= \frac{1}{s^2} \\
L[y] &= \frac{1}{s^2(s^2 + 2s + 3)} - \frac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 3}\\
L[y] &= \frac{1}{s^2[(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2]} - \frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

For the second term on the RHS, we have:

$$L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)\tag{2}$$

Let's write the first term on the RHS as:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{s^2[(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2]} &= \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s^2} + \frac{Cs+D}{s^2 + 2s + 3}\\
1 &= As(s^2 + 2s + 3) + B(s^2 + 2s + 3) + (Cs + D)s^2
\end{align*}

Putting $s = 0$, yields $3B = 1$, so $B = \frac{1}{3}$.

Expanding out the terms, we have:

\begin{align*}
1 &= A(s^3 + 2s^2 + 3s) + B(s^2 + 2s + 3) + Cs^3 + Ds^2\\
1 &= s^3(A + C) + s^2(2A + B + D) + s(3A + 2B) + 3B
\end{align*}

Comparing the coefficients,

\begin{align*}
A + C &= 0\\
2A + B + D &= 0 \\
3A + 2B &= 0
\end{align*}

$$A = -\frac{2}{3}\times B = -\frac{2}{9} \tag{3}$$

$$C = -A = \frac{2}{9}\tag{4}$$

\begin{align*}
2A + B + D &= 0\\
2 \times \frac{-2}{9} + \frac{1}{3} + D &= 0\\
-\frac{4}{9}+\frac{3}{9} + D &=0\\
D&= \frac{1}{9} \tag{5}
\end{align*}

So:

\begin{align*}\small L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^2[(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2]}\right] &= -\frac{2}{9} L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right] + \frac{1}{3}L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^2}\right] + \frac{2}{9}L^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2}\right] + \frac{1}{9\sqrt{2}}L^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(s+1)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2}\right]\\
&=-\frac{2}{9} + \frac{t}{3} + \frac{2}{9}e^{-t}\cos(\sqrt{2}t) + \frac{1}{9\sqrt{2}}e^{-t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)
\end{align*}

Putting everything together, we find:

$$ y(t) = -\frac{2}{9} + \frac{t}{3} + \frac{2}{9}e^{-t}\cos(\sqrt{2}t) - \frac{8}{9\sqrt{2}}e^{-t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)$$

whilst the answer provided in the text is:

$$ y(t) = \frac{2}{3}e^{-t}\cos(\sqrt{2}t) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}e^{-t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t) + t - \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Have you checked whether your result satisfies the differential equation and the initial conditions?

Comment: I figured this out. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: I've found a mistake: you substituted $y'(0)$ with $-1$.

Comment: Another one: you missed the factor of $3$ in $L[3t]$.